# Unable to authenticate with Microsoft using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement authentication with Microsoft using Firebase in my app. I followed the steps mentioned in the tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth.

Following are the code snippets from my application -

***MSAuthManager.java***

```
public void loginOutlook(Context context) {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    Task<AuthResult> pendingResultTask = firebaseAuth.getPendingAuthResult();

    if (pendingResultTask == null) {
        OAuthProvider.Builder provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("microsoft.com");
        provider.setScopes(asList(SCOPES));

        firebaseAuth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider((Activity) context, provider.build())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this)
                    .addOnFailureListener(this)
                    .addOnCanceledListener(this);
    }
}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<activity android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https://**********.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"
                  android:host="auth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

***Note - I have already authenticated the user with Google sign-in using Firebase on the Login Screen.***

However, when I start the authentication process, a custom tab launches takes me to the Microsoft login page and then automatically closes and redirects me back to my app with the following error -

`FirebaseAuthWebException: The web operation was canceled by the user.`

Could anyone please tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check the [Firebase Android quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth)? They have a [Microsoft sign-in sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GenericIdpActivity.java).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, and for me it's because the entered password is wrong so -> The web operation was canceled by the user.

You have to managed saved password or clear cache and data for chrome or samsung internet browser.